# How do I handle requests coming to grpc server asynchronously irrespective of the client?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am working on a C++ project where I have implemented a gRPC server. I would like to handle incoming requests asynchronously, regardless of the client.
In my C++ application, I have a gRPC server that receives requests from various clients and RPCs. Currently, I handle these requests synchronously, where the server waits for each client request to complete before processing the next one. However, I want to improve the server's performance by handling requests asynchronously, so that multiple requests can be processed concurrently.

I am seeking advice on the best approach to implement asynchronous handling of gRPC requests in C++. Specifically, I want to handle requests independently of the client, ensuring that the server is not blocked by any particular client request.

Some specific areas where I would appreciate guidance include:

1.How to design the server architecture to support asynchronous processing efficiently
2.How to handle concurrency issues and ensure thread safety when handling multiple requests simultaneously.

1.How to design the server architecture to support asynchronous processing efficiently
2.How to handle concurrency issues and ensure thread safety when handling multiple requests simultaneously.

Comment: Note that "seeking recommendations for code or software libraries" is one of the standard reasons for closing a StackOverflow question as off-topic; so you might want to remove parts (3) and (4) from your question to avoid that.

Comment: I see someone responded to your post here - https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/_rb6pVSLcDM